# How do I accept user input after the script in python?

Tags: python

I have a simple script called `cel2fer` to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit .  It looks like this:

```
Celsius = int(raw_input("Enter a temperature in Celsius: "))
Fahrenheit = 9.0/5.0 * Celsius + 32
print Fahrenheit
```

To run you type `cel2fer <ENTER>` in a terminal, then type a number like `10`, then `<ENTER>`, then it outputs the answer.  How can I modify this so you type `cel2fer 10 <ENTER>` and then outputs the answer?

Basically how can I accept something as an input that goes after the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sys.argv`, *a.k.a*, the list of command line arguments.

```
import sys

InputValue = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else raw_input("Enter a temperature in Celsius: ")

Celsius = float(InputValue)
Fahrenheit = 9.0/5.0 * Celsius + 32
print Fahrenheit
```

This way, if you enter a argument through the command line, the answer will be printed without querying the user. But, if you don't do so, then the program will query the user.

You may have a reading [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv) for more detailed information on the command line arguments.

I hope this has led a light on you!

**Edit**: Added support for float input values.